# CSS how to get current screen ratio

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the element size in proportion to the viewer screen ratio.

```
<style>
.element {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: calc(100vh/100vw * 100%);
}
</style>

<div class="element">
</div>
```

There seems to not be a CSS variable that defines the current screen ratio.

Screen ratio query is not preferable since this will require me to define every ratio.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll have to resort to a couple of lines of JS on load and resize. This could set a CSS variable of the aspect ratio then your CSS could use that throughout.

Comment: Thanks but that is not the solution that I seek.

Comment: I don't think there is another one! (that is, CSS doesn't have it built in as you have found).